# Django REST API with multiple representations/formats

Tags: python, django, rest

I'm new in web dev and I'm trying for a project to develop a Restful web api and a website. I'm using Django framework and following tutos, I always see html files as static and the different views rendering an html template. This way of doing seems to me as backend and frontend are not much separated. Is it possible to have backend only developed in Django ?

**edit:**

I have actually a problem more specific. I having this app (records) with a view having "patient_list" using Response class from REST framework that renders some data and an html template like this:

```
def patient_list(request):
"""
List all records, or create a new .
"""
if request.method == 'GET':
    #data = Patient.objects.all()
    data= Patient.objects.all()
    #serializer = PatientSerializer(data, many=True)
    #return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
    return Response({'patients': data}, template_name='records.html')
```

in my urls.py I have:

```
url(r'^records/$', views.patient_list),
```

and here I'm a little confused. Suppose one called this /records, so patient_list is called and will response with an html page. From what I understood (maybe wrong), a restful API should renders data in a standard view so that it can be used from any "frontend" (html pages or mobile app). Is this statement correct ? am I doing it wrong using Response with an html template ?

Comment: Yes, you can. Try to look at django-rest-framework

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### With Vanilla Django

Of course it's possible, and without any additional libraries to Django.

E.g. You can define a Django view that returns JSON data instead of rendering it into a HTML template server-side. Effectively making an API instead of a "website".

Here's an example with a [class-based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/class-based-views/intro/#introduction-to-class-based-views) that accepts GET requests and returns some JSON data with [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.http import JsonResponse

class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        my_data = {'something': 'some value'}
        return JsonResponse(my_data, mimetype='application/json')
```

As you can see, you don't *have* to use the HTML rendering facilities in Django, they're there only if you want to use them.

### With REST libraries

And of course there is a host of libraries to build RESTful APIs with Django, like [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and [Tastypie](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

### Multiple representations and content negotiation

> Content negotiation is the process of selecting one of multiple possible representations to return to a client, based on client or server preferences.

[You can support more than one *format* in your REST API](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/content-negotiation/). E.g. you can support both HTML and JSON formats. There are various ways to do this:

- You may use a GET param `?format=JSON` (and have it default to HTML e.g.)
- You may use `Accept` headers
- You may have two URLs `/records.html` and `/records.json` (the *format suffix* method)

More on this topic in [DRF's documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/format-suffixes/)

E.g. if you were to implement the first method with the GET params you could modify your code this way:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    data = Patient.objects.all()
    format = request.GET.get('format', None)

    if format == 'JSON': 
        serializer = PatientSerializer(data, many=True)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
    else:
        # Return HTML format by default
        return Response({'patients': data}, template_name='records.html')
```

Comment: Thank you bakkal. It is more clear now. Just a last thing. It is not wrong to use a template in the Response right ? I mean I'm still in the REST philosophy ?

Comment: I don't see a problem with that, because if you decide that your REST API server also needs to return HTML format, however you render it (with or without a template) is of no consequence to the client